# Can I put "Original Motion Picture Soundtrack" on my album cover (which is not a soundtrack)?

Tags: music

If I wrote an album with a soundtrack-"feel" to it, which (crucially) is not a real motion picture soundtrack, would I be allowed to put "Original Motion Picture Soundtrack" on the album cover for artistic purposes?

Comment: 10cc, "The Original Soundtrack", 1975.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. You could, assuming that you did not associate it with any real motion picture (which would be a trademark violation).

You'd probably want to clarify in fine print somewhere, however, to avoid confusing your fans.

Comment: I agree, that'd be disrespectful to fans, who will then be searching for the motion picture.  "Screenplay is done, ask your favorite studio to option it!" would be a sensible response; "there never was one" would not.